# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. when invoking bind on a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Code:

```
const renderSections = techSpecTableData.sections.map((section: Section, index: number) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="tech-spec-table-section">
            <div className="tech-spec-table-section__heading">{section.heading}</div>
            {renderRows.bind(this, section.rows)}
        </div>
    );
});
```

Warning:

```
[ts] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

What type should this have? I don't know actually. And I won't be using `this`. I just want to pass `section.rows`.

EDIT: Here is the full code of the component, which contains the part above but also other code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './TechSpec.css';

interface Section {
    heading: string;
    rows: Row[];
}

interface Row {
    label: string;
    values: string[];
}

const techSpecTableData = {
    ...
};

const renderRows = ((rows: Row[]) => {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            ...
        </div>
    );
});

const renderSections = techSpecTableData.sections.map((section: Section, index: number) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="tech-spec-table-section">
            <div className="tech-spec-table-section__heading">{section.heading}</div>
            {renderRows.bind(this, section.rows)}
        </div>
    );
});

const renderHeadings = techSpecTableData.headings.map((heading: string, index: number) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="tech-spec-table__header__heading">
            {heading}
        </div>
    );
});

const TechSpec = () => {
    return (
        <div className="tech-spec">
            <div className="content-container">
                <h2 className="heding--h2 heading--emphasized">
                    Technical Specification
                </h2>

                <div className="tech-spec-table__header">
                    {renderHeadings}
                </div>
                <div className="tech-spec-table__sections">
                    {renderSections}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TechSpec;
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `renderRows.bind`. Can you give us more context? i.e. where is `const renderSections` in your code?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Its in a functional component. It is called inside the JSX in the return function of the functional component with {renderSections}

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have edited the post to add context

Comment: the only usage where I think you should use bind is a event handler....

Comment: If you know a better way you are welcome to answer. I just want send the row data to another function that is responsible for rendering that so that each renderPart function does not become too large. Otherwise I thank you for the direction and will google on how this should be done tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` as you've used it will just be `window`, most likely. TypeScript probably doesn't know about it. Moreover, you most likely don't want to use it. Simply `renderRows(section.rows)` should be fine.

However, I would recommend that rather than have `renderX` functions you use components. It should be pretty easy to do this since you already have these as functions -- the transition to functional components should be pretty small.

```
const Section = ({ section }) => (
  <div>
    ... row content ...
  </div>
);

const Sections = ({ sections }) =>
  sections.map((section, index) => <Section section={section} key={index} />);

const TechSpec = () => (
  ...
  <div className="tech-spec-table__sections">
    <Sections sections={techSpecTableData.section} />
  </div>
  ...
);
```

Note that I would use `key={section.id}` or something like that if possible rather than `key={index}`.